# 'main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with' on windows computer

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, build, expo

I have developed a react native app and I wish to build it using expo. I have run 'eas build' from my terminal and it opens up an expo build. The expo build runs a series of operations but gets stuck on the run fastlane stage. The error is as the title describes. From looking at other threads I can see that many solutions require you to have XCode installed. I am using a windows computer to build for both iOS and android using react native. I was under the impression that react native will allow me to do this without interacting with XCode or needing a mac computer. I do not wish to eject my code into bare workflow format and want to let expo handle everything. Therefore I am confused as to what I can do to fix this issue?

I am fairly new to app development and using react native / expo so please forgive any inaccuracies.

Thanks

Comment: I just got this, how did you resolve it?

Comment: @mahmoudafer Not sure if this works for everyone but opening the .gitignore file, locating aws-exports.js and adding a '!' before it worked so it would read !aws-exports.js

Comment: In my case it was basically a tiny bug in the code that prevented it from generating the built bundle, seems like I made a change and forgot to build it locally to try it out before trying expo build